# CK Editor validates second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, ckeditor

I have two CKEditors in my HTML (I mean to say multiple ckeditors).

Also I am using Validate plugin for checking if CKEditor is empty,if empty show error.

Validation works perfectly, but it validates second time, whereas it should validate first time itself.

I have checked all the questions and answers here, but none helped.

I created a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mKcY/).

Code for validate :

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" id="frmEditor">

    <p>
        <label for="editor1">
            Editor 1:
        </label>
        <textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>

    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="editor1">
            Editor 2:
        </label>
        <textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" id="editor2" name="editor2" rows="10"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>

</form>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
// validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#frmEditor").validate({
        ignore: [],
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            editor1:{
                required: true
            },
            editor2:{
                required: true
            }           
        },
        messages: {         
            editor1: {
                required: "Please enter"
            },
            editor2: {
                required: "Please enter"
            }           
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }       
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code looks perfect but why are you using such old versions of jQuery and the plugin?

Comment: @Sparky , i tried using ALL versions,CAN YOU PLEASE add new validate plugin ,and jquery link in fiddle ,and tell me whether it works, I dont think its version problem,And changing version will make code work.

Comment: I just tried your jsFiddle in Safari and it's working perfectly.  The validation message appears on the first click.  Please explain exactly where you're seeing this problem.

Comment: @Sparky , No friend , I mean Do following steps => 1)Click on Submit(Dont fill Anything) 2)now fill on Editor1 3)Now click on submit. Now the error message will not be gone on first click 4) Now again click on Submit .Now validation is done ,And error message goes on 2nd click .please check

Comment: Please never put "resolved", "answered" or similar into the question title.  The little green checkmark next to your accepted answer is more than sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried following solution and it worked .

```
        <textarea name="txtDesc<?php echo $i;?>" id="txtDesc<?php echo $i;?>" class="ckeditor" rows="5" cols="17" ><?php echo $txtDesc?></textarea>
        <script>
         CKEDITOR.replace("txtDesc<?php echo $i;?>");
         CKEDITOR.add       
            //CKEDITOR.replace('txtDesc0'); 
        </script>
```

If there is only 1 ckEditor

```
for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {

    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].on("instanceReady", function () {

        //set keyup event
        this.document.on("keyup", function () { CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement(); });
        //and paste event
        this.document.on("paste", function () { CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement(); });

    });
}
```

If there are more than 1 ckEditor(in my case 2)

```
CKEDITOR.instances["txtDesc0"].on("instanceReady", function () {
this.document.on("keyup", function () { CKEDITOR.instances["txtDesc0"].updateElement(); });
this.document.on("paste", function () { CKEDITOR.instances["txtDesc0"].updateElement(); });
this.document.on("cut", function () { CKEDITOR.instances["txtDesc0"].updateElement(); });
});

CKEDITOR.instances["txtDesc1"].on("instanceReady", function () {
this.document.on("keyup", function () { CKEDITOR.instances["txtDesc1"].updateElement(); });
this.document.on("paste", function () { CKEDITOR.instances["txtDesc1"].updateElement(); });
this.document.on("cut", function () { CKEDITOR.instances["txtDesc1"].updateElement(); });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to update instance before validation performs. So first add an **id** attribute or class on button like this

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitFormBtn">
```

Now in your js code write below function

```
$('#submitFormBtn').click(function () {
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.updateElement();
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor2.updateElement();
});
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: [],
    // with this no hidden fields will be ignored E.g. ckEditor text-area
});
```

I observed the validation was working on 2nd submit. The reason is, `ckEditor` hides the actual text area and puts an iframe as an editor instance, and on submit it pushes the content to the text area. Which means, the validation on the `TextArea` gets fired on stale data. To fix this problem, I am updating my `TextArea` on the text change of the editor instance.

```
    for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].on('change', function ()
        {
            var editorName = $(this)[0].name;
            CKEDITOR.instances[editorName].updateElement();
        });
    }
```