# JQuery validate with CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using JQuery Validate and CKEditor and I am trying to get the CKEditor to validate code. It is not working. The validate works on all my other form components. How do I get it working for my CKEditor

My CKEditor is iniitialised like this

```
CKEDITOR.replace('description', {
    toolbar: [
        { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
        { name: 'list', items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList' ] }
    ]
});
```

My validator uses `data-rule-required` on the CKEditor but it does not validate it. Here is my JQuery valadation code.

```
if (jQuery().validate) {
    var removeSuccessClass = function(e) {
        $(e).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success');
    }

    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
        errorClass: 'help-block', // default input error message class
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if(element.parent('.chosen').length){
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            }
            if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            } else if(element.parent('.checkbox').length){
                error.insertBefore(element.parent('.checkbox'));
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
        focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
        ignore: ':hidden:not(.chosen)', // need line to validate chosen items that are shown.

        rules: {
            'send_email[]': {
                required: true,
                minlength: 1
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'send_email[]': {
                required: 'Must select at least one address',
                minlength: 'Must select at least one address'
            }
        },

        invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit
            var el = $(validator.errorList[0].element);
            if ($(el).hasClass('chosen')) {
                $(el).trigger('chosen:activate');
            } else {
                $(el).focus();
            }
        },

        highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
        },

        unhighlight: function (element) { // revert the change dony by hightlight
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
            setTimeout(function(){removeSuccessClass(element);}, 3000);
        },

        submitHandler: function(form){
            $('#save').hide();
            $('#saving').show();
            form.submit();
        }
    })

    $('#validation-form').validate({});
}
```

Comment: So, what do you want to ask?

Comment: Sorry, looking at why it isn't working

Comment: `It is not working.` MEANS? is it working?is it partially working? isn't it that any validation error evenif i fill Ckeditor box?Or it submits though its empty?Specify properly. Meanwhile i also faced such issue , check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323929/ck-editor-validates-2nd-time

Comment: It doesnt work, the validate doesnt trigger.

Comment: It's "not working" because the CKEditor does not fire the events that would trigger validation.  You have to manually force that to happen. You also have to make sure that you are validating the hidden items by changing `ignore` setting into `ignore: []`.  Did you click the link provided by Angry Bird?

Comment: I've done that with the ignore but then it breaks some of my other code. I currently use ignore: ':hidden:not(.chosen)' to stop validation on fields that were hidden due to jquery. Using ignore: [] with then make them validate but they will be hidden. Can I do a mulitple ignore rule?