# JQuery Validate CKEditor not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, ckeditor

I have a CKEditor and I am using the ignore item to make it work. `ignore: ':hidden:not(.chosen) :hidden:not(.ckeditor)',` This makes sure that I dont validate hidden fields. I found that I also need to do that for ckeditor to make it work. I validates ok if the textarea is required and nothing is entered but even if text is entered it still returns errors. I am using `data-rule-required` to set what is required and what isnt.

How can I get the validate to miss hidden chosen boxes and properly validate ckeditor

I have found that it will validate and allow form submission if I submit twice. Also if I already have the textarea populated and I am editing it by removing all the text then it will pass validation.

Comment: You need to manually trigger the validation plugin using the  `.valid()` method on a custom event trigger.  Otherwise, the standard event triggers built into the plugin are not fired.

Comment: @Pierce McGeough  , I had same issue, Check `My question` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323929/ck-editor-validates-2nd-time   Or mail me `nutandevjoshi@gmail.com` . Thanks

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird I got it working. I needed the second method you used. I just need to try and get the page to jump/focus on the non valid ckeditor

Comment: @PierceMcGeough , SIR , i had to find that Solution i got. Can you please do +1 ?I will tel u solution to ur current problem too.

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird yes done, :) I don't see why people downvoted the question though.

Comment: @PierceMcGeough , i recommand you asking Other question regarding `focus on ckeditor` , you surely will get answers.